# How to link two containers for a Jenkins Job?

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured my Jenkins to run our Build Jobs and functional Tests in a docker container. For example, when I click on the "Build Now"-Button - Jenkins will build the Dockerfile which is in Git and run the container so the Buildsteps (Jenkinsfile) can be done in this container.

My Question is now: How can I start another Container with MySQL-Server installed and link them to my Build-Job-Container everytime I Build my Job.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

one can use service discovery aka [Consul](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/consul-containers.html) as IPs in docker networks are granted dynamicaly. Or use static ip

```
docker run --net bridge --ip 172.17.0.254 -it ubuntu bash
```